# How do I add fade in fade out to inner HTML?

Tags: javascript, css

How can I get the fade in and fade out when the array item changes in inner HTML ? I would like it to fade out and disappear and then the next language to fade in to appear.

```js
var langs = ["Tamil", "Hindi", "Kannada", "Malayalam"];
var count = 0;
var langLength = langs.length;
var language = document.querySelector(".language");

setInterval(e => {
  count = count % langs.length;
    var newColour = langs[count];
    language.innerHTML = `${newColour}`
  count = count + 1;
}, 1500);
```

```css
.language {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  This language <span class="language"></span> <br>
  is an Indian language.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an infinite animation in CSS. Set the duration of the animation equal to the value used for `setinterval`.

```js
var langs = ["Tamil", "Hindi", "Kannada", "Malayalam"];
var count = 0;
var langLength = langs.length;
var language = document.querySelector(".language");

setInterval(e => {
  count = count % langs.length;
  var newColour = langs[count];
  language.innerHTML = `${newColour}`
  count = count + 1;
}, 1500);
```

```css
.language {
  font-weight: bold;
  animation: fadeOutIn 1.5s infinite;
}

@keyframes fadeOutIn {
  0%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  This language <span class="language"></span> <br> is an Indian language.
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Just out of curiousity, if I wanted to enhance this animation by sliding up/down for fadeIn/fadeOut, how would you suggest I proceed?

Comment: @scientific_explorer instead of animating the opacity, you can animate the top position.